# Separate processes

Tags: c#, architecture

I'm building a web applications that visualizes the flow of patients in a hospital.

The application is made up of 3 parts:

1. A process that reads messages from the network, converts them to a
   datamodel and stores them in a database. The messages are also passed to a second process
2. websocket server process: gets the messages from the first process and passes them to the website clients. Also processes websocket requests from the website.
3. The website itself (not relevant for the question)

I want to seperate process 1 and 2. Meaning that when the websocket server process crashes, the first process should keep running.

I wonder how I best do this. The second process wants to subscribe to new messages from process 1. I currently do this via events.

Is there a standard way in .net to seperate the prcesses so they can run independently?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Tarscher, why do you use a websocket server process for the second part of your application. When the first part of your app stores all information in a database, why you don't use this data for your website?

Comment: because I dont want to poll the database all the time for changes. The first process sends the second process new messages 'realtime'

Comment: Why separate processes instead of separate threads?

Comment: How often do you expect a message from the first process? Do you need a "realtime" processing in your app?

Comment: You can develop a windows service that hosts two native .net AppDomain using isolation http://geekswithblogs.net/elinden/archive/2008/09/12/application-processing-isolation-welcome-the-appdomain-object.aspx and WCF to communicate between AppDomains.

Answer (score 1):

I'd remove process number 2 from the equation and code process 1 as a windows service that reads from the database and publishes the messages using MSMQ. The your website can poll the queues periodically (maybe an ajax call to an ashx) and refresh it status.

This way you get reliable messaging by MSMQ, fire and forget for process 1 and the ability to read whenever you want from your website

Answer (score 0):

You can run each process in a different app domain.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173139(v=vs.80).aspx

Best regards.